# Converting log odds coefficients to probabilities

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

Suppose we've ran a logistic regression on some data where all predictors are nominal. With dummy coding the coefficients are ratios of log odds to the reference levels. A colleague claims that we can "solve for $p$" or "apply the inverse logit to the estimated parameters" interpret the result as relative probabilities, but my intuition tells me that the logit function isn't so well behaved. See the more concrete example below:

```
mydata<-data.frame(outcome = rbinom(1000, 1, 0.3),
                     Race=sample(c("White", "Black", "Hispanic", "Other"), 1000, replace=TRUE), 
                     Gender=sample(c("M", "F"), 1000, replace=TRUE))                    
myglm <- glm(outcome ~ Race + Gender, family=binomial(), data=mydata)
x <- summary(myglm)$coefficients[,1]
cbind(coef_log_odds = x, coef_prob = exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)) * 2)

#              coef_log_odds coef_prob
# (Intercept)    -1.09760895 0.5003763
# RaceHispanic    0.18458782 1.0920327
# RaceOther       0.08886623 1.0444039
# RaceWhite       0.04471730 1.0223549
# GenderM         0.40350628 1.1990596
```

We see that `coef_prob` for `GenderM` is 1.199. Can this be interpreted as "holding all else fixed, males are 1.2 times as likely as females to have `outcome1`"?

Comment: You've applied *twice* the inverse logit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relation between odds & probabilities is non-linear, so a model with a constant odds ratio between males & females doesn't translate into one with a constant probability ratio (a.k.a. [relative risk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk)) between males & females—the latter depends on the intercept & values of other predictors. And you apply the inverse logit function to get a probability from an odds, not to get a probability ratio from an odds ratio.

Here the probability ratio between black males & black females is

$$\frac{\frac{\exp (-1.0976 + 0.4035)}{1 + \exp (-1.0976 + 0.4035)}}{
\frac{\exp (-1.0976)}{1 + \exp (-1.098)}}\approx 1.331$$

while that between Hispanic males & Hispanic females is

$$\frac{\frac{\exp (-1.0976 + 0.1846 + 0.4035)}{1 + \exp (-1.0976 + 0.1846 + 0.4035)}}{
\frac{\exp (-1.0976+ 0.1846 )}{1 + \exp (-1.098+ 0.1846)}}\approx 1.311$$

If you had another race with a large odds ratio the probability ratio could be very different.