# Binary logistic regression - SPSS

Tags: regression, prediction, biostatistics, causality

I did some regression analysis in SPSS using two binary variables:
**Biomarker X** (0= low levels; 1= high levels), where 0 was the reference category and **Obesity** (0=no; 1=yes)

''Biomarker X'' was taken as the independent variable and ''Obesity'' as the dependent variable. The following results were obtained: Exp(B)= 6.5; 95% Confidence Interval for Exp(B)=1.09-38.63; Sig.=0.040. I interpreted these results as follows: **Biomarker X is a predictor of obesity and subjects with high levels of Biomarker X have a 6.5 fold increased risk of obesity compared to subjects with low levels of Biomarker X.**

To my surprise, exactly the same values were obtained when ''Biomarker X'' was the dependent variable and ''Obesity'' the independent variable, which would mean that Obesity is a predictor of high levels of Biomarker X.

While these results might be statistically valid, they make absolutely no sense from a biological/medical point of view…

I would therefore appreciate your help with the interpretation of these data. Furthermore, it would be great if you could recommend additional statistical tests that might clarify these results.

Comment: You have a 2x2 table of counts (obese, not; high, low). Are the counts balanced?

Comment: Counts are as follows:
not obese, low Biomarker=8; 
obese, low Biomarker=8; 
not obese, high Biomarker=2; 
obese, high Biomarker=13

Comment: *Prediction* makes perfect sense; *causal implications* might not. As an analogy, consider the relationship between ice cream sales at a beach resort and temperature. High sales reliably predict high temperatures--and high temperatures reliably predict high sales.  That's not problematic. But nobody would seriously contend that we can control the weather by selling ice cream.  Analogously, in your case it's perfectly plausible *biologically* that obesity and the biomarker are mutual predictors--and they're equally good at that, given the symmetric binary relationship between them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hope the reviewers for our paper will see it the same way :-)

Comment: Note the exponentiated coefficient estimates are odds ratios not relative risks: see [Converting log odds coefficients to probabilities](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94987/17230).